# EXCEL: SUMIF with 3 criteria across 2 rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

See the data in the image below. I want to calculate the sum of all budgets, planned and actual values for a given Costcode for all months until current month (current month is July).

I tried sumifs and sumproduct as well but couldn't get it to work. Can someone help me?

I appreciate your help a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With *50345* in AO2, try it as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A9=AO2)*(B1:AM1<=7)*(MOD(COLUMN(B:AM), 4)<>1)*B3:AM9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot has some columns hidden, but I assumed that the pattern continued.  I also assumed that you would want these totals to change automatically as the months go by.  With that being the case, I continued your pattern out for 12 months.  Then, I put in 4 summary columns.  One for each code vertically and one for each row header.  Then, I created this formula in cell AX3 (and copied right and down):

```
    =SUMIFS($B3:$AW3,$B$2:$AW$2,AX$2,$B$1:$AW$1,"<="&(MONTH(TODAY())))
```

It is an array formula.  If you have never used an array formula, follow these steps:

1. select the formula from this page
2. copy it
3. go to excel
4. select cell AX3,
5. press the 'F2' key
6. paste the formula
7. press CTRL+SHIFT+Enter (instead of just pressing enter)

To copy down, follow these steps:

1. Copy cell AX3
2. Move down to cell AX4 (instead of selecting a range)
3. Paste in cell AX4
4. Select your range and paste from there.

If you don't copy down in this manner, it will tell you that you cannot change the array...

[image: screenshot of my answer]